# How to Parse Timezone with Single Digit Offset? "Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT-8 1969"

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have this date:

```
"Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT-8 1969"
```

But it cannot be parsed with this SimpleDateFormat:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

How do I specify the `-8` in the format string?  I have tried `Z` and `X` after reading the SDF docs, but to no avail.  What should I use?

Comment: Beware: Using a single digit for the [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is **not standard** ([ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)). Will cause problems with various libraries and protocols that correctly expect double-digits with padding zero for single-digit values.

Answer (score 3):

The use of `-8` is in a non ISO standard format.

Something like `-0800`  or `-08:00` is expected. This is because the time offset can include half hours.

You should run a preprocessing conversion on the string before passing it to the SimpleDateFormat and change it to `"Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT-0800 1969"` 
and use:

`new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy");`

If you want to make it simpler just create a method to replace the `-8` with `America/Los_Angeles` and use `ZZZ`.

Comment: This works as the preprocessing conversion: `s = s.replaceFirst("([\\-\\+])(\\d)\\b(?!:)", "$10$200").replaceFirst("([\\-\\+])(\\d\\d)\\b(?!:)", "$1$200");`.  It handles - or + followed by 1 or 2 digits, but leaves sequences of 3 or more digits alone as well as sequences followed by `:`.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using java 8, you can try `DateTimeFormatter` with a pattern of `"EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss O yyyy"` likes:

```
    String date = "Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT-8 1969";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss O yyyy");
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);
```

`O` represent localized zone-offset and can format zone offset like GMT+8, GMT+08:00, UTC-08:00. You can see `Offset O` in [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for more details.