# SimpleDateFormat for Oracle Date (TimeStamp with TimeZone)

Tags: java, oracle, simpledateformat, splunk

I am currently trying to parse a Datestring (TimeStamp with TimeZone) coming from an Oracle Database using a [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). This is mandatory as the resulting Pattern is supposed to be used in Splunks DBConnect. The String I recieve has the format:

```
2018-07-24 14:00:02.876611 +0:00
```

I am currently trying to use

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S XXX
```

as pattern String (minimal Example at the end). As far as I understand, the problem is with the timezone having no leading 0 (e.g. +00:00 would work).
Is there still a way to parse the date using a SimpleDateFormat with a simple Pattern?

Thank you very much in advance.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "2018-07-24 14:00:02.876611 +0:00";
        String parser = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S XXX";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(parser);
        try {
            Date date = format.parse(input);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

## Update I:

In my oppinion this is not a duplicate question due to the limitation of using a SimpleDateFormat Pattern. The [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277202/how-to-parse-timezone-with-single-digit-offset-wed-dec-31-000000-gmt-8-1969) does neither state wheter or not it could be done using a SimpleDateFormat nor (if possible) how the pattern must be created. It offers the solution to either use another library (not possible) or use preprocessing (not possible).

## Update II:

It is not possible to preprocess the data, as the access to the database is limited. And the possibility to add further preprocessing in Splunk is also not possible.

Due to the way DBConnect (the application that is going to be using the Pattern) is developed it expects a Pattern that is SimpleDateFormat compliant.

I understand that the answer to this question is, that it is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Parse Timezone with Single Digit Offset? "Wed Dec 31 00:00:00 GMT-8 1969"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38277202/how-to-parse-timezone-with-single-digit-offset-wed-dec-31-000000-gmt-8-1969)

Comment: Apparently, this can't be done purely with `SimpleDateFormat`. There's simply no suitable pattern to handle single digit offsets. You'll need to preprocess date strings before passing it to `SimpleDateFormat`, I'm afraid.

Comment: Also `SimpleDateFormat` can never parse a 6 digit fraction of second (microseconds).

Comment: what about `Instant dateResult = OffsetDateTime.parse(
                "2018-07-24 14:00:02.876611 +0:00".replace("+0:00", "+0000"),
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS Z")
        ).toInstant();` using **java.time**

Comment: What hindrances do you meet to using another library (even another built-in API) and to preprocessing? If you explain, we might be able to suggest. As your question stands, I am afraid that all we can say is “no, there is no way to parse the date string using a `SimpleDateFormat` with a simple format pattern”.

Comment: In the best of all possible worlds you would not be getting a datetime string from Oracle. You would be getting a real datetime object like an `Instant` or an `OffsetDateTime`. Modern JDBC drivers and modern JPA implementations are happy to give you that.

Comment: I think that after *Update II* I understand you situation. I don’t know Splunk nor DBConnect. I think my first step would be to investigate whether DBConnect can fetch the timestamps out of the database without converting them to strings underway.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes this would be possible. However, if we were to use it as a String, it would either not be possible to use splunks built in functionality to filter (e.g. events in the last 24h) or result in the need to integrate a post processing script (not supported in this use case)

Comment: Is it possible for you to reframe your question in terms of Oracle/Splunk integration (e.g. "how can i pass this query result from Oracle to Splunk DBConnect")? Perhaps, with additional details (e.g. where the data is coming from) somebody will be able to provide an alternative. Your question might be an example of [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).